# How to send query parameter as integer instead of String in Postman?

Tags: java, spring-boot, query-string

I need to send a query parameter as an integer instead of a string in Postman and I know how to do that. I know it might sound like a simple question but I can not find an answer to it

Comment: Query parameters are always String, it is when you read it that you have to decide what it is

Comment: @user16320675 is for a spring boot app :)

Comment: @Bentaye I use CriteriaAPI and it expects that parameter as an integer

Comment: @user16320675 I am using CriteriaAPI which expects an integer for that query parameter, and potman sends it as string, and I want to know if I can send it as Integer if I can

Comment: As @Bentaye the query parameters are always strings.  In Spring Boot you use the method parameters to define how the parameters are converted, you will also need to use the appropriate annotation for the parameter so Spring Boot knows which query parameter to map to method parameter.

Comment: perhaps this might help: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

Answer (score 1):

Parameters sent over HTTP are always down-bottom strings as HTTP is text based protocol.